# How do I migrate from OpenLDAP to Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, openldap

currently we are running samba and openldap as our PDC.  our ultimate goal is to migrate completely over to windows active directory.  how would i go about doing this?

Comment: You're doing it wrong! </fanboy> I have very little experience with LDAP; why are you migrating?

Comment: migrating because my manager wants me to.  not sure if there is any other reason.

Comment: "Because X told me to" is a pretty lousy reason to migrate -- There are plenty of good ones & I would discuss them with management.

Comment: Demanding that your manager justify their decisions before you start researching how to do it is generally not a healthy career move.

Comment: true.. far better to demand a fortnight's offsite training course. Wouldn't want to get it wrong after all, think of the cost to the business :)

Comment: thanks for your comments guys.  currently, i'm doing research on how to accomplish this and if it's at all possible.  i'm trying to use LDIFDE to export data from the current DC but not having any luck.  i may have to scrap this plan altogether.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Migrating to Windows is going a step back. You should go forward with adding kerberos support for authentication. You gotta reason with your manager.

Comment: Having Group Policy, if you have any number of Windows machines, is very, very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking this can be treated the same as adding/migrating to any other DC:

1. Join two Windows servers to the domain.
2. Make the windows servers into backup DCs.

   1. See the Windows documentation & any notes your admin team has on this process
3. Make the OpenLDAP PDC go away (Again refer to notes/docs, but you want to unplug it, then disjoin it)

   1. Universe still working?  If so, continue. Otherwise Find out why & *fix it*.

      1. Can't fix it? Revert back to the OpenLDAP PDC until you can!
4. Promote one of the Windows boxen to be PDC (not sure if this is still necessary or not these days?)

   1. Universe still working? If so you're done. If not, *fix it*

      1. (You shouldn't ever get to 4.1 :)

Comment: I worry that you're using PDC and BDC as operational terms when we're talking about AD domains.